# Getting the top row by a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a small df:

```
binary_model %>% group_by(nrounds, eta) %>% summarise(pr_auc = mean(pr_auc))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   nrounds [3]
  nrounds   eta pr_auc
    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1      25  0.05  0.150
2      25  0.1   0.301
3      50  0.05  0.299
4      50  0.1   0.301
5      75  0.05  0.299
6      75  0.1   0.578
```

Data:

```
binary_model %>% group_by(nrounds, eta) %>% summarise(pr_auc = mean(pr_auc)) %>% dput

structure(list(nrounds = c(25, 25, 50, 50, 75, 75), eta = c(0.05, 
0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1), pr_auc = c(0.149813492616464, 0.300964818237437, 
0.299190666192169, 0.301285494726815, 0.299330635113509, 0.577719446100828
)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(nrounds = c(25, 50, 75), .rows = list(
    1:2, 3:4, 5:6)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

I would like to get the row with the best prauc. So row 6 in this case.

Tried:

```
binary_model %>% group_by(nrounds, eta) %>% summarise(pr_auc = mean(pr_auc)) %>% top_n(1, pr_auc)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   nrounds [3]
  nrounds   eta pr_auc
    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1      25   0.1  0.301
2      50   0.1  0.301
3      75   0.1  0.578
```

This returns 3 rows, expected just one.

I know I could use `dplyr::arrange` and then select a the first row; but if there's a less code and more elegant way I would prefer that. Perhaps I'm using `top_n()` incorrectly?

Comment: Use `ungroup()` after the `summarise` or `.groups="drop"` as argument of `summarise`.

Comment: Perfect, this got me what I needed thanks!